# Apache 2.4 VirtualDocumentRoot and www alias at once

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost, mac-osx

Here's my vhost file:

UseCanonicalName Off

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    VirtualDocumentRoot /Users/username/Sites/%-2+
    ServerName test
    ServerAlias *.test
</VirtualHost>
```

I use it for my local development. Under directory ~/Sites i have all the site folders, for example: ~/Sites/myblog. This virtualdocument thingy is working well, except for www to non-www redirect. If i type in a browser: www.myblog.test it throws an error "Not found". How can i make it work as www.myblog.test and myblog.test together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the example you gave, you would need:

```
VirtualDocumentRoot /Users/username/Sites/%-2
```

Have a look at https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html, under "Directory Name Interpolation"

```
-2  the penultimate part
```

while yours is:

```
-2+     the penultimate and all preceding parts
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked, lol. I didn't understood "penultimate part"

Comment: I assure you, I had to deduce it myself.

Comment: is there a way to "debug" it? -1, +1

Comment: No idea, but I'd have a look in the error log when I'd have a 404.